# DBpedia results changed over time

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I run a query on DBpedia using jena framework, as part of a project, on January 2016 to count the distinct properties of 100 movies. I was writing the report yesterday so I tried to confirm the results, but surprisingly they have changed. On January, I got 100+ properties, yesterday I got 63. I used the same query the same everything!

I even saved the list of properties labels in my hard disk on January that confirm there were 100+. I checked if all of them are still used to describe movies resources on DBpedia, I found that many of them are not. I also had a look at the changelog of their website and this is the only thing I found that may be relevant is on the page (http://wiki.dbpedia.org/dbpedia-version-2016-04) that says:

> We now filter out triples from the Raw Infobox Extractor that are
>   already mapped. E.g. no more “ dbo:birthPlace ” and “
>   dbp:birthPlace|dbp:placeOfBirth|... ” in the same resource. These
>   triples are now moved to the “infobox-properties-mapped” datasets and
>   not loaded on the main endpoint. See issue 22 for more details.

do you think this is the reason, or do you know any explanation to that?

The query I've used :

```
select (count(distinct ?pr) AS ?count) where {
    ?su ?pr ?ob .
        select ?su{
        ?su a <http://schema.org/Movie> .
        }
    limit 100

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: A possible cause is that the server is truncating the results - DBpedia has some resource limits and the query does potentially scan a significant part of the database.

To eliminate this, try at different times and different days.  If the 63 is same each time it is unlikely to be a resource restriction cutting in.

Comment: Actually I thought of that, so I tried to list 1000 subjects and there were no problems. And also, the restriction is applied usually when you run the query on the public endpoint. I am using a java/jena program.

Comment: I think this is the reason `We now filter out triples from the Raw Infobox Extractor...` before you got more properties that were most times synonyms

Comment: @jimkont yes I think it may be the case. And it is not just synonyms, there are some properties missing from some resources that existed before, for example: rating, release data..etc

Comment: @M20 — Note that the public service's resource limits (query timeouts, result rowcounts, etc.) apply no matter whether you're using the HTTP-based SPARQL endpoint, Jena/Java/JDBC, ODBC, or otherwise. Also, I'm quite sure you're not using the query as seen here and now, because it uses invalid syntax. That said, you might try your correct query on <http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql>, <http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql>, <http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql>...

Comment: @TallTed you're absolutely correct. I got almost the same numbers that I have from January from one of the links you provided (the last one), thanks! Could you please copy/paste your comment as a response so I can mark this thread solved and you take credit for it.

Comment: @M20 can you give some examples, we should fix that is this is the case. This is tracked here: https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/issues/22

Comment: @jimkont when I run a query to count the distinct properties of 100 movies, I used to get 90~93, and for 200 I get 110~115 ..and so on. Now, no matter the limit of movies you apply, you still get 63~65. The page of the version 2016-04 says that properties synonyms (duplicates) are not loaded anymore. But I think it would've been better if you give the choice to the user on whether he wants to hide this redundancy or gets the datasets as they are.

Comment: we did not throw them only moved them out of the main endpoint, they are still available here http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-04/core-i18n/en/infobox_properties_mapped_en.ttl.bz2. DBpedia Live does not yet have this feature yet, can you find some examples there where we miss useful data?

Comment: @jimkont I may need a separate program to verify whether there're useful data missing. But at a glance (copy and search), and without considering their synonyms, I can see that I have some properties in my old files that do not exist now e.g: film_set_designer, lyrics_Credits, film_regional_release_date etc. 

Not only that, I can find syntactic duplicates even though my query asks for distinct properties. For example: if you run a corrected version of my query for 200 movies, you'll find dbo:narrator repeated twice.

I'm not sure whether it's something to fix, these are just suggestions.

Comment: Distinct can be a separate issue here. The new code is supposed to reduce only "synonym" raw properties. If you can identify counterexamples we can try a& fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the public service's resource limits (query timeouts, result rowcounts, etc.) apply no matter whether you're using the HTTP-based SPARQL endpoint, Jena/Java/JDBC, ODBC, or otherwise.

Also, I'm quite sure you're not using the query as seen here and now, because it uses invalid syntax.

All that said, you might try your correct query on

- http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql
- http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql
- http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql

(The last certainly hasn't been updated with the new DBpedia data set yet, but it may be at any time, so adopting a disclaimer will be in your best interest.  Something like, "This is a publicly-editable, living data set, being extracted from Wikipedia by an evolving codebase, so results may (and will, and have) change over time.")

Comment: In addition to the disclaimer, it is possible to refer to a specific DBpedia version as dumps are available at least for the last versions.

Answer (score 2):

There was a new DBpedia release last week, thus, the public endpoint contains the latest dataset only.

And I don't think that the changelog is complete regarding all changes in the data. Of course, the comment you mentioned reduces the number of properties for a single resource, but without seeing your query I cannot say anything else.

If you really need the old data, you can still download the dumps and load it into your local triple store.

Comment: I've updated the question and I included the query. The rest of the code is a simple ResultSet display.

Do you think I can use the comment I posted as an explanation (in your opinion) ? Cause I can't afford to start over again, and the number of the properties is just an input of bigger operations. Therefore, I need to justify why it may give you different results if you try the same think on a different time.

Comment: "This is a publicly-editable, living data set, being extracted from Wikipedia by an evolving codebase, so results may (and will, and have) change over time."